# Iterate through multiple arrays and check if all elements are non-empty (or strlen is at least 1)

Tags: php, arrays

For example have 3 arrays. With `$_POST` the arrays looks like

`$_POST['row_id']` - `$_POST['row_id'][0]`, `$_POST['row_id'][1]`, etc.

`$_POST['date_day']` - `$_POST['date_day'][0]`, `$_POST['date_day'][1]`, etc.

`$_POST['date_month']` - `$_POST['date_month'][0]`, `$_POST['date_month'][1]`, etc.

Want to iterate through `$_POST['row_id']` and then if `$_POST['date_day']` and `$_POST['date_month']` are non-empty create new array `$if_non_empty` with value 1.

Data are these:

`$_POST['row_id'][0]` is 1

`$_POST['row_id'][1]` is 2

`$_POST['date_day'][0]` is 1

`$_POST['date_day'][1]` is blank/empty

`$_POST['date_month'][0]` is 4

`$_POST['date_month'][1]` is 4

Created this code

```
foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
if ( (strlen($_POST['date_day']) >= 1) and (strlen($_POST['date_month']) >= 1) ) {

$if_non_empty = 1;

print_r ($if_non_empty);
echo ' $if_non_empty<br>';
}

}
```

So what I expect

code first time goes through `foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {`

then first time goes through `if ( (strlen($_POST['date_day']) < 1) and (strlen($_POST['date_month']) < 1) ) {`

as `$_POST['date_day'][0]` and `$_POST['date_month'][0]` are non-empty (values 1 and 4), then creates array $if_non_empty[0] with value 1.

But the code displays nothing. Tried with empty and non-empty values.

This

```
print_r ($if_non_empty);
echo ' $if_non_empty<br>';
```

displays nothing.

My final aim is like this

1) With the code above I want to create array `$if_non_empty`. Depending on `$if_non_empty` I can manage only arrays with non-empty values.

2) Then iterate through `$if_non_empty` and insert the arrays with non-empty values into mysql.

There are multiple input rows with multiple values for each row.

Some input fields in a row may be empty. Such input rows I do not want to insert.

Such is a solution I try to create to insert only rows where all input fields are non empty.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the php manual.

strlen return the length of the string on success, and 0 if the string is empty.

better use empty function http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: watch out for empty because given `$a = "0";` empty returns true

Comment: @Jack since `$_POST['date_day']` and `$_POST['date_month']` are both arrays and the user just wants to check if they are not empty, why it's not appropriate?

Comment: Because `empty()` will also be `true` for things like `'0'`, which is a non-empty string.

Comment: yes, that's true. If I'm not aware of the type, I would'nt use `empty()`. but if you have an array (and that's the case in this question), `empty()` is in my opinion appriopriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is questionable:

```
if ( (strlen($_POST['date_day']) < 1) and (strlen($_POST['date_month']) < 1) ) {
```

You just said `$_POST['date_day']` and `$_POST['date_month']` are arrays so I don't truly know what you are achieving with this if statement. Do you mean to do this?

```
if ( (count($_POST['date_day']) < 1) && (count($_POST['date_month']) < 1) ) {
```

More info on [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) which takes in a String as a parameter, not an array. Also [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Hope that helps.